# Hash a string in python and return a binary result

Tags: python, token, wowza, hashlib

I'm looking to implement the following secure stream using Wowza Engine.

https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-protect-streaming-using-securetoken-in-wowza-streaming-engine

In order to do that I need to produce a sha256 hash of a string in python. When I hash my string using sha256 and call hexdigest I get a hex string as the result.

When I call digest I get a byte array. I'm looking to produce the equivalent of this php code.

```
$hashstr = hash(‘sha256’, ‘live/definst/test.stream?c7800e7e5afc8c0b&wowzatokenendtime=0&wowzatokenstarttime=0’, true);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php

The piece I can't quite figure out is the binary return flag in php. From the docs above:

```
Returns a string containing the calculated message digest as lowercase hexits unless binary is set to true in which case the raw binary representation of the message digest is returned.
```

My  current code:

```
import base64
import codecs
import hashlib

from datetime import datetime

base_url = 'rtsp://server.domain.com:1935/'
prefix = 'vodTest/_defaultVHost_/sample.mp4?'
secret = 'SECRET_STRING'
wowza_end_time = '1646394821'

def test():
    print(get_rtsp_hash_string())


def get_rtsp_hash_string():
    
    string_to_hash = prefix + '&wowzatokenendtime=' + wowza_end_time + '&' + secret

    return  base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha256(string_to_hash.encode('utf-8')).digest()).decode()

def get_url():
    
    return base_url + prefix + '?' + 'wowzatokenhash=' + get_rtsp_hash_string()
```

Any suggestions appreciated?

Thanks,

Shawn

Comment: Wrap it in `bin()`

Comment: The output is a hex string value, not an integer. Where should I inject the bin() call?